# Clean Architecture and user

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I try to implement clean architecture in a small app Android ( just to test this clean Architecture). but after I want to test kotlin/multiplatform.
But I can't figure out how can I do with user.
My example is user can be freemium or premium. For freemium, data are stored in room database and for premium in a server. Of course app design change if you are premium/freemium.
I create a UserUseCase where I can get the user information. But the problem is I need this user for ui and db and this information is needed in all others usecases and I have to call everytime for getUser to have the information about user.
For domain:

```
data class User (

        var id : String = "",
        var city : String = "",
        var country : String = "",
        var email : String = "",
        var name : String = "",
        var status : Int = 0

        )
    
class UserUseCase(userRepository: IUserRepository) : IUserUseCase {
    
    override fun getUser(): User = userRepository.getUser()
}
```

For another use case :

```
class NoteUseCaseImpl(private val noteRepository : INoteRepository, private val userRepository : IUserRepository) : INoteUseCase{


    override fun getNotes(): List<Notes> = noteRepository.getNotes(userRepository.getUser())

    override fun createNote(note: Note) = noteRepository.createNote(note, userRepository.getUser())

}
```

And after in repository :

```
class NoteRepository(private val localNoteRepo, private val serverNoteRepo) : INoteRepository{
 override fun createNote(note:Note, user : User){
    if(user.status == Status.Premium)
       serverNoteRepo.createNote(note)
    else localNoteRepo.createNote(note)

}
```

}
But I need for UI to do again a "getUser" to know if his status is Premium or Freemium and so I have add "getUser" everywhere ( UseCase, viewModel etc...)
Is there a better solution ?
I saw a lot of examples on stackOverflow and google it, but I can't find a good solution.
If you have any example... Thank you

Comment: You can't store premium user only on server side. It should be stored in local db too to be available at offline mode. Just use a field at User class to set freemium/premium state. Encrypt db or save user data at preferences and encrypt preferences https://proandroiddev.com/encrypted-preferences-in-android-af57a89af7c8

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't user but data (like preferences, wishlist, ... ).Data are saved in local database for freemium or on a server  if premium. Of course user information ( like name, isPremium, isFreemium) is saved in sharedpreferences and on server. My question is more about architecture and clean architecture. Where and how to get user instance in every layer of clean architecture...

Comment: Yes, to request user by getUser call is a good idea. https://hannesdorfmann.com/android/evolution-of-the-repository-pattern/

Comment: If you need complex data including user instance you can join all of them to an entity (defined at domain level)  and return from repository. So you can inject some repositories at interactor/useCase or single repository. It depends on realization of entities in your app.

Comment: Please provide a code of any use case (e.g. wish list) where you use getUser request

Comment: I updated with code. It may be more clear

Comment: There is a similar question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/378285/access-multiple-entities-in-repository-clean-architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get user status and create note are two different use cases for ui. For the second one you can request user status from domain layer only.

```
class NoteUseCaseImpl(private val noteRepository : INoteRepository, private val userRepository : IUserRepository) : INoteUseCase{
    override fun createNote(noteText: String, noteDate: Date): Note {
        val user = userRepository.getUser()
        val premium = user.status == Status.Premium 
        return noteRepository.createNote(noteText, noteDate, user.id, premium)
    }
}

class NoteRepository(private val localNoteRepo, private val serverNoteRepo) : INoteRepository{
    override fun createNote(noteText:String, noteDate: Date, userId: String, premium: Boolean): Note {
        return if(premium)
           serverNoteRepo.createNote(noteText, noteDate, userId)
        else 
           localNoteRepo.createNote(noteText, noteDate, userId)
}
```

Any way you should save the note in local db too. So you need improve this variant using a repository refresh strategy

Comment: Ok, thanks for this solution. It's not an app for production so I know it makes no sense to record data in local database or in sever instead of record data in local database and server. But there's just one point about UI, if I  decide that premium can choose a color for note so I need to get user status. I thought to getUser with a viewModel(UserUseCase) inside fragment note. Is it a good idea , I think it's very redundant.

Comment: You can create one more use case like UserUseCaseImpl.isUserPremium() that returns Boolean. After that set the note color according the output value of the use case

Comment: Thank you. My last question : in NoteUseCase is it good if I add canChooseColor() and after I check if user is premium or not is it good with Clean architecture ?

Comment: Color manipulation refers to UI. So good place for canChooseColor call is presentation layer. Run the call depending on UserUseCaseImpl.isUserPremium() call. Sample for Rx: fun canChooseColor(): Observable<Boolean> = userUseCase.isUserPremium()